# Laravel not working method updateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel

The user has a profile setting. I want if the user changes some fields to be updated. But I have a new column created and should be updated. Maybe someone is not doing it right. Help please. Thank you very much.

Controller

```
     public function profile_settings_post(Request $request){
          // Auth Specialist
          $user = Auth::user();
          // Data Specialist Validate
          $data = $request->validate([
              'first_name' => 'nullable|string',
              'last_name' => 'nullable|string',
              'phone_number' => 'nullable|integer',
              'gender' => 'nullable',
              'date_of_birth' => 'nullable',
              'about_me' => 'nullable',
              'address' => 'nullable',
              'city' => 'nullable|string',
              'country' => 'nullable|string',
              'postal_code' => 'nullable|integer',
          ]);
            $profile = $user->profile_settings()->updateOrCreate($data);
            $profile->save();

          // RETURN REDIRECT PROFILE SETTINGS INDEX
        return redirect()->route('frontend.specialist.profile.settings');
    }
```

User Model

```
 class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public static function countPercent($count, $maxCount){
        //one percent
        $one_percent = $maxCount / 100;
        // $count how much is percent
        $percent = $count / $one_percent;
        return $percent;
    }

    // 1 User have 1 profile settings (ONE TO ONE)
    public function profile_settings(){
        return $this->hasOne(Profile_Settings::class);
    }

}
```

Profile_Settings Model:

```
 class Profile_Settings extends Model
{
    // Fill in db
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number',
        'gender', 'date_of_birth', 'about_me',
        'address', 'city', 'country', 'postal_code',
    ];

    // Profile settigns model belongs to User
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

[image: User profile settings]

When I edit some kind of field. A new field is created in the database

[image]

profile settings database not working update create new columns

Comment: If i understand this correctly, when updating the profile settings, you're creating a new record with the updated data instead of updating an old record with updated data, so you end up with two records old/not updated) - (new/updated) right?

Comment: Remove `$profile->save();` line. `updateOrCreate()` already saved data it to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't read carefully how works updateOrCreate
It performs update based on the condition that you're passing in and updates the fields, that you want, so you will have to pass 2 arrays.

Example from Laravel's webitse

```
// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

So this means we are updating all rows, where 'departure' = 'Oakland', 'destination' = 'San Diego' and setting price to 99$.

I your case you should decide the condition, when you should perform update query, it will be 1st array, and also decide which fields should be updated, put it in 2nd array.

Comment: can you please help. I can not. I try all the options all the same does not work.

Comment: Please describe when and what exactly should be updated (condition and fields) and I will try to help.

Comment: I will tell you my task. the user has a setting profile model. When the profile of the new field is not yet filled. When it is filled, the column in the base is displayed. But maybe something will change over time. I need to update the same column, and not create a new column.